# Dynamically Create ExpandableListView

Tags: android, dynamic, expandablelistview

I am trying to create an ExpandableListView dynamically in my application. The parent rows display the dates of the next 7 days and I retrieve the children from a web-service. But, fetching and displaying the children are not my problem. I am facing trouble in displaying the parent rows dynamically. I need to display the dates of the next 7 days in the parent rows.

I declared this empty array of strings globally.

```
private String[] parent = new String[7];
```

Then, inside onCreate(), I used this code to create the parent array contents.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String strdate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {

        if (cal != null) {
            strdate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            }
            parent[i] = strdate;
           cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
    }
```

But, the activity gives a NullPointerException at MyExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView().

(Maybe because the parent array has not be initialized initially ?)

because the code works when I declare the parent array initally as

```
private String[] parent = new String[] {"","","".....};
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your problem but you are creating your date strings wrong. First of all you add 0 hours to `cal` (24 * 0) then you add, 24, 48, 72 etc. This is accumulative however so you'll get today, tomorrow, 2 days after tomorrow, 5 days after tomorrow etc. Try adding to the 'date'and leave `i` out of it...`cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)` - that should also rollover the `MONTH` if it goes past the end of the current month.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I stopped multiplying i to it. The strings are displayed properly when I declare the parent array initially, but I want it to be done dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution : **Static Block** was the answer to it. I put the code to create the parent array contents inside a static block instead of `onCreate()` and it works like a charm now.